# R shiny Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r

I wonder if anyone can help me to figure out the following problem

```
ui = fluidPage(
      mainPanel(
       .......
       fluidRow(
             textInput("res",h4("size")) 
             )
          )
      )
server = function(input,output){
         index1 = reactive({...})
         index2 = reactive({...})
         index3 = reactive({...})
         index4 = reactive({...})
observe({
   x = renderText(
       if(input$selc2=="EMT"){
       as.character(EMT[index1(),2])
   }else if(input$selc2=="SUS-304"){
           as.character(SUS[index2(),2])
        }else if(input$selc2=="RSG"){
           as.character(RSG[index3(),2])
        }else{
           as.character(PVC_p[index4(),2])
        }
        )
})
    updateTextInput("res",
                   value = paste(x))
}
```

I am trying to update the textInput value, but it always show the

`error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'chracter'`
EMT,SUS,RSG,PVC_p are .csv files

Comment: Please share some sample data so we can try to reproduce your error.